# Boot linux in text mode and without framebuffer?

Tags: linux, framebuffer

This used to be the default some years ago: Linux would boot up on a text console, 80x25 characters. I want to get back to that - this is for a number of servers that boot over the net (with PXE) - some of them have a GPU (NVIDIA) installed and need to use the non-free NVIDIA driver, so nouveau is not and option. The servers have no need for GUI - the GPUs are for computation only - and they will not normally have a monitor attached, but it may occasionally be useful to see the console, say if there is an error at boot.

Is it possible to start linux without framebuffer, but keeping the text console?

==== ***EDIT*** ====

Forgot to mention which linux I'm using: Debian 11

==== ***EDIT 2*** ====

Just to round this off, it would appear that this may be an error in the linux kernel version 5.x. The `efifb` driver is compiled in, and it just can't handle it, so I have decided to give up for now.

So why not try a version 6 kernel? Well, I need to mount a lustre filesystem, and the client doesn't compile (yet) on that version, so I am stuck with this, at least for now.

Comment: Use `nomodeset`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I already did, but then I have no text consoles at all.

Comment: Your kernel configuration is borked. Take it to your Linux vendor or compile in the appropriate modules if you use your own build.

Comment: What Linux distribution do you use?

Comment: @paladin Debian 11 - I'll add it to my question as well

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? If the system boots in BIOS mode, then the VGA text mode should be available, but if in UEFI mode, the `efifb` driver might be the only way to access the display.